# Angular changes JSON string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, json.net

I'm trying to show some data on screen using AngularJS, ASP.NET and JSON.NET. When I'm calling `$.getJSON` it returns a normal JSONArray, but when I'm putting the data in a this.variablename inside my Angular controller, the data changes and Angular won't display it in my view.

**Model**

```
public class Directory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<int> DirectoryIds { get; set; }

    public virtual Directory Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Directory> Directories { get; set; }
}
```

**.NET controller action**

```
public string GetDirectories()
{
    var directories = db.Directories.Where(d => d.ParentId.Equals(0)).ToList();

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { directorylist = directories }, Formatting.Indented,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    });
}
```

**Angular JS**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('notes', []);

    app.controller('DirectoryController', function () {
        this.directories = directories; //Check output 1
    });

    var directories = $.getJSON("/Directory/GetDirectories", function (data) {
        return data; //Check output 2
    });
})();
```

*Output 1* (larger image http://i62.tinypic.com/2ppd0kg.png)
[image: The output that Angular makes of my JSON]

*Output 2*

[image: This is what I actually want to use but gets changed in output 1]

Comment: you might consider switching to the angular resources or the angular `$http.get()` function instead of using a jquery function; aside from that, both frameworks implement the get function asynchronously, so you should set your data in the success function, instead of assigning it to the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Claies commented and Protector one answered, the getJSON call was asynchronous and this way I couldn't fill the `var directories` before my page loads.

The answer was to use `$http.get` from within the controller and use a variable to store the context of the controller, which I have done with `var cont = this`. Then I needed to initialize my `directories` variable with an empty array to avoid errors on page load.

Then later on I just assign `data` from within the success `Promise` to my `directories` variable.

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('notes', []);

    app.controller('DirectoryController', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var cont = this; //Save the context
        cont.directories = []; //Empty array to avoid errors on page load

        $http.get('/Directory/GetDirectories').
          success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              //Save the async data to directories in the right context
              cont.directories = data;
          }).
          error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          });
    }]);
})();
```

Thanks for the help. Both the comment from @Claies and the answer from @Protector one helped me to find a fit answer myself.

If anyone has a better answer, feel free to post it, so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

[getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) asynchronously retrieves the data, and doesn't actually return it.
You could try to set up your controller in the `success` parameter function:

```
var directories = $.getJSON("/Directory/GetDirectories", null, function (data) {
    app.controller('DirectoryController', function () {
        this.directories = data;
    });
});
```

Also note that the first parameter of `getJSON` is a data object that is sent to the server; in your example you provide it a javascript function.